# Estimate parameter in $x(t) = A \cdot \sin{\left(\omega \cdot t + \varphi \right)} + A_0$ through least squares method

Tags: regression, optimization, chi-squared-test, software

I have a bunch of data $(x_i, \, t_i)$ that is expected to distribute like $x(t) = A \cdot \sin{\left(\omega \cdot t + \varphi \right)} + A_0$.

Now I have to estimate the four parameters $(A, \, \omega, \, \varphi, \, A_0)$. So I want to minimize the formula (variances on $x_i$ are all the same, and the variances on $t$ are irrelevant): $$ f(A, \, \omega, \, \varphi, \, A_0) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \cdot \sum_{i=i}^n (x_i - A \cdot \sin{\left(\omega \cdot t + \varphi \right)} - A_0)^2$$

And then I have to solve the system

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} = 0\\ 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \omega} = 0 \\ 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi} = 0 \\ 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A_0} = 0
\end{cases}
$$

And get:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \cdot \sum_{i=i}^n -2 \sin(\varphi + \omega t_i) (-A \sin(\varphi + \omega t_i) - A_0 + x_i) = 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \cdot \sum_{i=i}^n -2 A t_i \cos(\varphi + \omega t_i) (-A \sin(\varphi + \omega t_i) - A_0 + x_i) = 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \cdot \sum_{i=i}^n -2 A \cos(\varphi + \omega t_i) (-A \sin(\varphi + \omega t_i) - A_0 + x_i) = 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \cdot \sum_{i=i}^n -2 (-A \sin(\varphi + \omega t_i) - A_0 + x_i) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

But, at this point, I can't go ahead. I don't know how to solve the system because I couldn't separate parameters out of sum.

Has anybody any tips to solve the system? Or an alternative method to obtain the parameters? Any software for such minimization I can use?

Comment: Why $\chi^2$? That Greek letter has a particular meaning in statistics, and it looks like you’re just doing a straightforward, even if messy, nonlinear least squares fit.

Comment: @Dave You're right, what I really want to do is a least squares fit.. but I thought taht what I have to minimize is called $\chi^2$ .. maybe I can edit my question to specify better what I'm trying to do. Thanks

Comment: You 'can' use $\chi^2$ as a loss function, but you don't have to. I'd recommend starting with least squares.

Comment: @Galen What is $\chi^2?$ Is that a particular type of loss function? This looks like a nonlinear regression with square loss.

Comment: @Dave You can use the familar $\chi^2 = \sum_i \frac{O_i - E_i}{E_i}$ as a loss function, even on non-integer variables. I think Jaya 'should' use square error instead.

Comment: @Galen Jaya is using square loss.

Comment: Yes. I have not checked the edit history to see where $\chi^2$ came into the picture.

Comment: You can use the Solver in Excel to minimize the original expression - I'd recommend having bounds on your variables. Unfortunately, it's not straight-forward to guarantee that you'll find the global minimum, but the Solver is quite good at what it does.

Comment: @Adrian This is a problem we can expect Solver to do poorly with unless it is very intelligently controlled.  Thus, your recommendations are spot-on: it's crucial to begin with good estimates and bounds.

Comment: For an interesting thread in the literature on the value of initialization of a parameters, I recommend reading [All you need is a good init](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06422) and [All You Need is Beyond a Good Init](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01827).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An algebraically equivalent model (with the random error term $\epsilon$ explicitly added) is

$$\begin{aligned}
x(t) &= A_0 + A\left[\cos(\phi)\sin(\omega \, t) + \sin(\phi)\cos(\omega\, t)\right] + \epsilon\\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1\sin(\omega \, t) + \beta_2 \cos(\omega\, t) + \epsilon
\end{aligned}$$

where

$$\begin{aligned}
A_0 &= \beta_0\\
A &= \sqrt{\beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2}\\
\phi &= \arg(\beta_1,\beta_2) = \operatorname{Atan2}(\beta_1,\beta_2).
\end{aligned}$$

By using the principal arctangent, the ambiguity in the original formulation is eliminated: $A$ will be non-negative and $\phi$ will be in the interval $(-\pi,\pi].$

*Given* any fixed value of $\omega,$ this is an ordinary least squares model for the remaining parameters $\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2$ and can be efficiently solved. Let the estimates associated with any such $\omega$ be $(A_0(\omega), A(\omega), \phi(\omega))$ and let the sum of squared residuals associated with those estimates be $\sigma^2(\omega).$  This reduces the problem to

> Minimize $\sigma^2(\omega)$ given $\omega$ lies within a reasonable range of frequencies.

This is a *one* dimensional problem which needs to be solved numerically.  Confidence intervals, *post hoc* tests, and so on, can be conducted in the usual ways (by making distributional assumptions about $\epsilon$ and applying Maximum Likelihood, for instance).

---

Some readers with access to nonlinear modeling functions might think this analysis is unnecessary.  However, fitting this model correctly is tricky: $\sigma^2(\omega)$ typically has many local minima.  Even when you can supply reasonable starting values for the search it still can go awry.  Thus, it's an advantage to have an independent solution.  Having found it, you can use its estimates as starting values for your black-box solver in order to exploit the solver's added capabilities.  (The `R` function `nls`, for instance, supplies enough information for hypothesis testing.)

As an example, I generated the dataset of values plotted by the orange points below by randomly varying the values of the gray ("True") curve.  The dotted black curve was fit using the method described above (using the `nlm` function in `R` to estimate $\omega$ and its `ls` function for the OLS calculations).  It is a reasonable approximation to the truth.  The blue curve is the `nls` solution based on reasonable starting values for the parameters.  Its phase and frequency are very wrong.

[image: Figure]

To reproduce this figure, uncomment the `#set.seed(17)` line in the code below.  To develop some intuition for this problem, leave the line commented and play with the parameters at the beginning to vary the circumstances and study the solutions.

```R
#
# Specify the (true) parameters.
#
A0 <- 5
A <- 2
phi <- 3*pi/4
omega <- -24
sigma <- 1  # SD of the error terms
n <- 87     # Data set size
#
# Formulate the model.
#
f <- function(t, A0, A, phi, omega) {
  A0 + A * sin(omega * t + phi)
}
#
# Specify the data.
#
X <- data.frame(t = cumsum(rexp(n, n)))
# set.seed(17)
X$x <- f(X$t, A0, A, phi, omega) + rnorm(n, 0, sigma)
#
# Plot the data and the data-generation model.
#
with(X, plot(t, x, pch=21, bg="Orange"))
curve(f(t, A0, A, phi, omega), add=TRUE, lwd=2, col="Gray", xname="t")
#
# Define the function to optimize.
#
ols <- function(omega, data) {
  fit <- lm(x ~ sin(omega * t) + cos(omega * t), data)
  list(SS=sum(residuals(fit)^2), b=coefficients(fit))
}
h <- function(omega, data) {
   ols(omega, data)$SS
}
#
# Estimate omega.
# It is crucial not to make the upper limit too large: otherwise, the 
# solution frequency will be too great.
#
# Need a reasonable starting value.  Estimate it with FFT:
#
X <- X[order(X$t), ]
y <- with(X, approx(t, x, seq(min(t), max(t), length.out=nrow(X)))$y)
omega.0 <- which.max(Mod(fft(y)[seq_len(n/2)][-1])) * 2 * pi * diff(range(X$t))

obj <- optim(omega.0, h, data=X, method="Brent",
      lower=omega.0/3, upper=omega.0*2)
omega.hat <- obj$par
#
# Compute A0, A, phi from b.
#
b <- ols(omega.hat, X)$b
A0.hat <- b["(Intercept)"]
A.hat <- sqrt(sum(b[c("sin(omega * t)", "cos(omega * t)")]^2))
phi.hat <- atan2(b["cos(omega * t)"], b["sin(omega * t)"])
#
# Plot the estimated curve.
#
curve(f(t, A0.hat, A.hat, phi.hat, omega.hat), add=TRUE, lwd=2, lty=3, xname="t")
#
# Independently apply nls as a check.
#
A0.0 <- mean(X$x)
A.0 <- diff(range(X$x))/3
phi.0 <- 0 # This is difficult to guess, so start anywhere
#
# Alternatively: Polish the nlm estimates with nls.
#
# A0.0 <- A0.hat
# A.0 <- A.hat
# phi.0 <- phi.hat
# omega.0 <- omega.hat

obj2 <- nls(x ~ A0 + A * (sin(omega * t + phi)), data=X, 
            start=list(A0=A0.0, A=A.0, phi=phi.0, omega=omega.0),
            control=list(maxiter=200))
a <- as.list(coefficients(obj2))
blue <- "#4080ff80"
curve(f(t, a$A0, a$A, a$phi, a$omega), add=TRUE, lwd=2, lty=1, col=blue, xname="t")
#
# Compare the estimates.
#
ss <-  ols(omega.hat, X)$SS
ss2 <- sum(residuals(obj2)^2)
if (ss < 0.999 * ss2) warning("nls is worse.")
#
# Plot decorations.
#
legend("top", bty="n", cex=0.9, title="Key:",
       legend=c("True", "nlm", "nls"),
       lty=c(1, 3, 1),
       col=c("Gray", "Black", blue),
       lwd=2,
       bg=NA)
```

Comment: Good answer! But I suppose I don't have enough knowledge for trurly understand what are you saying.. (I'm a beginner). Infact, what I did is to find $\omega$ wrt the other parameters supposing them as constant. But, then I don't know how to handle it.. I mean, I don't know how to estimate the other parameters from now.. but thanks for your time!